# Dagger2 to Hilt Migration Missing Binding

Tags: java, android, kotlin, dagger-2, dagger-hilt

I am having a hard time with understanding how Hilt builds the dependency graph with the usage of EntryPoints. I have managed to use @HiltAndroidApp annotation within my Application class.
My main AppComponent looks like that now:

```
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
@Module(
    includes = [
        ModuleX::class,
        ModuleZ::class, ]

interface AggregatorModuleApplication

@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
@EntryPoint
interface AppComponent {
    fun mainActivityComponent() : MainActivityComponent
    fun inject(application: AppApplication)
    fun serviceComponent(serviceModule: ServiceModule): ServiceComponent
  ...  (other fun returning components) }
```

That worked with such App class:

```
@HiltAndroidApp
class AppApplication :
open val appComponent: AppComponent = EntryPointAccessors.fromApplication(this, AppComponent::class.java)
appcomonent.inject(this)
```

Now I would need @AndroidEntryPoint inside Activity I have. What I did is add annotation @AndroidEntryPoint to it and this is MainActivityComponent interface:

```
@InstallIn(ActivityComponent::class)
@Module(
    includes = [
        Module0::class,
        Module1::class,
        Module2::class,...]

@InstallIn(ActivityComponent::class)
@EntryPoint
interface MainActivityComponent {
    fun inject(activity: MainActivity)
    fun componentOne(): ComponentOne
    fun componentTwo(): ComponentTwo }
```

Now inside My Activity I call:

```
 private val mainActivityComponent =
      EntryPointAccessors.fromActivity(this,MainActivityComponent::class.java)
```

Error:
error: [Dagger/MissingBinding] com.projecthilt.di.MainActivityComponent cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method.
public abstract static class SingletonC implements AppApplication_GeneratedInjector,

What is wrong here or how should I take care of  -> fun componentOne(): ComponentOne
If this is an

```
@Subcomponent
interface ComponentOne {
    fun inject(fragment: FragmentX)
    fun inject(fragment: FragmentZ)
    fun inject(fragment: FragmentY)
```

Comment: Does it work to remove your `fun mainActivityComponent()` from AppComponent? Its presence on AppComponent may convince Hilt that it needs to supply its method return values in Singleton scope absent your Activity bindings. My hunch is that your transition to Hilt is very incomplete—you don't need an explicit MainActivityComponent or ComponentOne (fragment component) at all—and those are tripping up Hilt. You should instead use [@AndroidEntryPoint](https://dagger.dev/hilt/android-entry-point) so Hilt can populate its hierarchy appropriately. If this sounds close, I'll write it up as an answer.